# How to ignore a column for select distinct in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, union, distinct

Hello everybody!

I have a SQL (see above) and i would like to know how i can make sure that i don't get doubles concerning the name only. if a name appears in the first Select it's the master and should be ignored in the following selects.

```
"SELECT name, id, 'place' AS tablename FROM places WHERE lower(name) LIKE '".strtolower($needle)."%'"
    ."UNION SELECT name, id, 'community' AS tablename FROM communities WHERE lower(name) LIKE '".strtolower($needle)."%'"
    ."UNION SELECT name, id, 'district' AS tablename FROM districts WHERE lower(name) LIKE '".strtolower($needle)."%'"
    ."UNION SELECT name, id, 'region' AS tablename FROM regions WHERE lower(name) LIKE '".strtolower($needle)."%'"
    ."UNION SELECT name, id, 'province' AS tablename FROM provinces WHERE lower(name) LIKE '".strtolower($needle)."%'"
    ."ORDER BY name LIMIT 10"
```

this is my SQL.

do u need more information?

thanks

Comment: it's just for testing how that works, security comes next ;-)

Comment: could you tell me where the injection is? i am now at the security step ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`DISTINCT`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) name, id, tablename 
FROM (
    SELECT name, id, 'place' AS ... 
    UNION ... 
    UNION ... 
    UNION ... 
    UNION ...) AS subQuery
ORDER BY name LIMIT 10
```

Just specify to only do distinct on the `name` by using your query as a sub-query.

Do the limit and ordering during the distinct, otherwise the distinct might discard dupes and not give up the full 10 rows in the correct sorted order.

Comment: if i add it to each select, different tables are selected disticnt, but in the union i have doubles.

Comment: thanks ... but doesn't work at all :-(

i have to use an alias for the subquery ... Select Distinct ... FROM(...) AS subqueryname ORDER ...

now it works